# Why does my IEnumerator<AppiumWebElement> not have .Where()?

Tags: c#, appium, ienumerable

The title mostly explains my question, my `IEnumerable<AppiumWebElement>` does not have a `.Where` method, and I'm hoping to learn why.

I have a method that returns an `IEnumerable<AppiumWebElement>`, as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<AppiumWebElement> GetLayers()
{
  var items = PaneOrView.FindElementsByClassName("TreeViewItem");
  List<AppiumWebElement> layers = new List<AppiumWebElement>();
  foreach(AppiumWebElement item in items)
  {
    string automationId = item.AutomationId(); 
    if (automationId != null && automationId.Contains("Layer"))
    {
      layers.Add(item);
    }
  }
  return layers.AsEnumerable();
}
```

When I check whether `.Where` is present on the return item in this method (using code completion), I get a full list of methods I would expect to see from an `IEnumerable`.

However, when I later use this method from another namespace, for example like this:

```
var test = Contents.GetLayers();
```

The result in `test` doesn't contain `.Where` or any of the other methods I would expect to see from an `IEnumerable`. Any idea why?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Make sure you are using the LINQ namespace (`using System.Linq;`)

Comment: `Where` is not a member of `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`, it's an _extension_ method: in class `Enumerable`, declared as `public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)`

Comment: Ah bingo, that solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where()` and other methods in `Linq` are extension methods that you are using. You need to import `System.Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;
```